# ESでIterableなクラスを作る

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

ES2015 ClassesでIterableなClassを作りたいです
Pythonだと`__iter__`と`__next__`というメソッドを実装すればIterableなクラスを作成できますが、ESではどうすればいいのでしょうか?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols, https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators が参考になると思います。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

プロパティ名が`Symbol.iterator`シンボルであるメソッドを定義します。
また、Generator メソッドにすると楽です。

```
class A {
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield 1;
        yield 2;
        yield 3;
    }
}

const a = new A();
for (const item of a) {
    console.log(item); // 1 2 3
}
```

他の例:

```
class B {
    constructor() {
       this._list = [1,2,3];
    }

    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        for (const item of this._list) {
            yield item;
        }
    }
}

const b = new B();
for (const item of b) {
    console.log(item); // 1 2 3
}
```